# How to implement sign out functionality from social networks in Yii auth

Tags: yii, facebook-social-plugins, yii-extensions, yii-components

Iam using Yii auth extension for login to my website using social networks like facebook, linkedin, twitter etc. Iam able to sign in to the website using the extension. But my problem is that when I signout from my website the accounts of the corresponding networks is not signing out. How can I implement it correctly ?

Comment: check *[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483594/how-to-log-out-user-using-facebook-sdk/11537046#11537046)*, its realted to facebook signout,

Comment: @LoverOfEvening  But it is only about facebook..
I need to implement logout for all the other social networks included in the site.
Is there any general way??

Comment: i haven't' implemented anything yet, search the net bro.. otherwise build one your own and publish it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using access_token from social network we can logout . 
for fb logout Iam using the below code
 $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=' . $returnurl. ' &access_token=' . $token;
        session_destroy();
header('Location: ' . $url);