# facebook logout php v.3.2.2

Tags: php, facebook, logout

I am working on the Facebok PHP SDK v.3.2.2.

I am facing issues in logout, when I click on the link it goes to facebook home page.

SDK Code:

```
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'http://[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]/facebook/examples/logout.php'));
```

In HTML Code, onclick of button it call the logouturl.

I tried multiple ways of look in Stack Overflow and Google but could not found any solution.

Need Help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483594/how-to-log-out-user-using-facebook-sdk).
Due to some reason it wasn't working before, but after some changes it work.
If anybody needs the code, you can contact me on akshay.sarkar.dbit@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

try this;

$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('***redirect***' => 'http://[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]/facebook/examples/logout.php'));

Comment: Hi avalkab, i tried this .i have given the url properly but it seems to redirect to same page rather than specified one. Under Developer Tools when i checked for the same the url,it looks
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.222.136%2Ffacebook%2Fexamples%2Fexample.php&access_token=_sometoken_&redirect=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.222.136%2Ffacebook%2Fexamples%2Flogout.php

I have two doubts in the url:
1 - there is next and redirect both ,is that okie. ihave only specified redirect.
2- On the click its coming to same page,so i understand its taking next parameter not redirect

Comment: Redirect url has %3A and %2F for characters ':' and '/' under developer tools, eg: redirect=http%3A%2F%2F[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]%2Ffacebook%2Fexamples%2Flogout.php


Is it okie or do we need do some character encoding over here.