# How to logout the user in facebook after failure to register an account?

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

Right now I have implement the facebook login like this

Firstly, generate an login url

```
        $this->data['login_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'redirect_uri' => site_url('secure/login_fb'),
            'scope' => array("email") //permission
        ));
```

and after redirect check and register the user in the system.

The problem is , **if the user can not register in the system, the facebook login record is still there,**

but I would like to remove the session and allow the user to login again using the other facebook account

how to logout and remove the session using PHP facebook SDK?

Try

`$this->facebook->destroySession();` but the login session is still there

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483594/how-to-log-out-user-using-facebook-sdk, check first answer there

Comment: You probably need to log the user out: `getLogoutUrl()`